# Does Phonegap's SharedPreferences support storing files in xml format?

Tags: android, cordova, sharedpreferences, phonegap-plugins

I have googled a lot but didn't got the proper answer. Does phonegap for android support SharedPreferences to store key and values in xml format?

Comment: anything going wrong there?

Comment: why you are rejecting my answer once in a day. :)

Comment: I aint its automatically rejecting and accepting ,,,i think something going wrong...

Comment: okay np. thanks for confirmation.

Answer (score 3):

Phonegap is not providing SharedPreference directly.

There may be different ways to follow the same scenarios.

```
   [1] You can make plugin calls from phonegap code to Android and use SharedPreference there.

   [2] You can use html5's localstorage as well, if there is no need of storing large amount of data.
```

Edited :

```
   [3] You can also use JavascriptInterface to achieve such functionality. This will be more easy then implement custom phonegap plugin.
```

This are some ways and may be there are many available also.

This you can implement easily.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: does  html5 local-storage stores the data in XML format.because i need a human readable data-storage format.and the second question is fro plugin call do i need to develop a phone-gap plugin for calling to android code from java-script.Thanks @Pratik

Comment: In html5 local-storage you can store values in key-value pairs, and yes that would be human readable you can fetch and reuse them. For phonegap plugin, yes you need to make plugin for that and follow all steps to make it working.

Comment: See I have edited my post and added one more solution which you can use easily too.

Comment: html5 local storage is it indexedDb or it is webSQL...which is your talking about i am new to web tech....Do you have any working example for the third one..

Comment: Look at this example : [https://github.com/scottagarman/Android-JavaScript-Interface-Example]  and this also [http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.in/2011/09/android-javascriptinterface-tutorial.html].

Comment: sorry these two is invalid link one is saying show this post is not available other is show this is private repository....

Comment: remove square bracket "]" from both links and open again.

Comment: @Abhijit if its somehow helpful to you then you can accept/vote my solutions I provided. Thanks.